# Laravel 4 Eager Loading "Undefined Property"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Why can't I access the property in an eager loaded senario?

I am trying to access the photo location for my facilities model. They have a Many:Many relationship. When I load the facility info using

```
$facilities = Facility::with('photos')->get();
```

When I try to access

```
foreach($facilities as $facility)
{
    echo $facility->photos->id;
}
```

I get the `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id`

If I echo `$facilities->photos` I end up with.

```
[{"id":"3",
"name":null,
"location":"facilities\/facility1.jpg\r",
"created_at":"2013-07-18 14:15:19",
"deleted_at":null,
"updated_at":null,
"pivot":{"facility_id":"5","photo_id":"3"}}]
```

Whats the best way to access any property in this array?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With eager loading the `photos` you get a `photos` collection and in order to get the photo you need to iterate through the `photos` collection e.g.

```
foreach($facilities as $facility)
{

 foreach($facility->photos as $photo)
 {
    echo $photo->id;
 }

}
```

If you only want just the first photo you can get it by calling the `first()` method on the collection

```
foreach($facilities as $facility) 
{
  $facility->photos->first()->id;
}
```

Comment: `$facility->photos()->first()->id;` should be `$facility->photos->first()->id;` (no parenthesis on photos).

Answer (score 2):

What is received from the database is an array with one object. This is why a foreach works. To access it the way you want you should add the first() method just as Atrim says, you can even drop the get() method. Only I would suggest doing it in the controller.

```
$facilities = Facility::with('photos')->first();

{{ $facilities->location }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Altim, I just hit this problem too and the nested foreach is one of the solutions.
Nevertheless, I'll share with you guys the solution that I used at the end.

Instead of the nested foreach or even the eager loader, I used a Join Query Builder. In my case:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->get();
```

This allowed me to use one foreach, and all the data is at the same level, in my case for instance would be something like:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
  <p>{{ $post->first_name }}</p> # From users table
  <p>{{ $post->title }}</p> # From posts table
  <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Maybe it is not answering this question exactly , but hope it helps to others like me that ended up in this particular question.

Comment: If someone know a way of doing a clean left join without query builder, in a more laravel way, I would love to know it ;)